# Running a command line bitcoin CPU miner on ubuntu for slush's pool

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, poclbm

I don't intend to do this long term as I am pretty sure the cost of the power would exceed the earnings, this is more for educational purposes. What I'm looking for is a command line miner for Ubuntu. What I've tried so far is using `poclbm.py`

```
./poclbm.py -d 0 http://worker:pass@api.bitcoin.cz:8332
```

however this only gives me

```
No PyOpenCL


Not using OpenCL


Nothing to mine on, exiting
```

I've found several guides on how to use `poclbm` however they seem to be out of date. That is to say that the command line arguments don't match up with the current project. I also have pyserial installed.

To sum it all up I don't care if I use `poclbm` or not I'm just looking for a tool to get up and running.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use one of the updated cpuminer versions which support more than one algorithm. This way you are also set up to mine different coins which use other PoW functions. The most versatile one is tpruvot's fork:[cpuminer-multi](https://github.com/tpruvot/cpuminer-multi). For me this one worked out of the box on a recent Ubuntu 14.04 installation.

The syntax is similar to all other cpuminer versions:
cpuminer -a sha256d -o stratum+tcp://pool.com:port -O username.workername -p password

Answer (score 3):

After spinning-up my [Raspberry Pi](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01C6Q2GSY) and registering an account at [slushpool](https://slushpool.com) I've had success with the following process:

1. `sudo apt-get install automake autoconf pkg-config libcurl4-openssl-dev libjansson-dev libssl-dev libgmp-dev make g++ git`
2. `git clone https://github.com/tpruvot/cpuminer-multi`
3. `cd cpuminer-multi`
4. `./autogen.sh`
5. `./build.sh`
6. Check out the commands: `./cpuminer --help`
7. `./cpuminer -u slashpool_user_name.slashpool_worker -p pass -a sha256d -o stratum+tcp://stratum.slushpool.com:3333 -t cputhreads`
8. For Litecoin: `./cpuminer -u slashpool_username.slashpool_worker -p pass -a scrypt -o stratum+tcp://stratum.slushpool.com:3333 -t cputhreads`

Answer (score 2):

You can use [cpuminer](https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer). Just make sure you have all the dependencies, compile, and run:

```
minerd -o stratum+tcp://name-of-pool.com:port -O username.workername:password
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://omidraha.com/en/latest/src/crypto_currency/mining.html#poclbm), worked for me:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/m0mchil/poclbm
$ cd poclbm
$ poclbm.py omidraha.worker1:anything@jp.stratum.slushpool.com:3333
```